# OOP. Passing arguments correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

This works:

```
class Thing():
    def __init__(self):
        a=2
        exec(f'self.foo ={a} + 2')

x = Thing()
print(x.foo)
```

This does not works works:

```
a=2

class Thing(a):
    def __init__(self, a):
        exec(f'self.foo ={a} + 2')

x = Thing(a)
print(x.foo)
```

**Question:** How to make second example to work properly (it should put `2` inside `x`)?

Comment: Why in the world are you using `exec` for something like this?

Comment: Your title appears to have nothing to do with the question. Please fix

Comment: @MadPhysicist Easy way of doing metaprogramming. Security and performance is not an issue in that particular case.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think problem here is correctly passing arguments. Do you have any suggestion how to improve title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Thing: #Note: Not Thing(a)
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.foo = a + 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `class Thing(a)` with `class Thing()` and you are good. The argument to the class name is the class you are inheriting from, not the argument to instatiation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use 'a' as argument when you defined it out of class:

```
a=2 
class Thing: 
    def __init__(self): 
        exec(f'self.foo ={a} + 2') 

x = Thing()
print(x.foo)
```